# Prove that: $\hat{\lambda} \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \hat {\lambda} (A_n) $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $P = \{[a,b), -\infty < a \le b < \infty\}$.

Put: $\lambda:  P \to [0,\infty), \lambda([a,b)) = b-a$.

Then, we have the following useful facts:

- $P$ is closed under finite intersections, and the difference of two elements of $P$ is a finite union of elements of $P$.
- If $(I_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of disjoint elements of $P$, such that $\bigcup_n I_n \in P$, then we have: $\lambda(\bigcup_n I_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda(I_n)$.

We would like to extend $\lambda$ over the ring generated by $P$.

It is proved that the ring generated by $P$ is:

$$R(P) = \left\{ A \subset \mathbb R \mid \exists \ I_1,...,I_n \in P, A = \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k \right\}$$

Now consider: $\hat{\lambda}: R(P) \to [0,\infty)$, which to each element $A \in R(P)$ assigns $\hat{\lambda}(A) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda(I_k)$, where $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^nI_k$, and the $I_k$'s $\in P$ are **disjoint**.

I was able to prove all of the following except the last one:

- $\hat{\lambda}$ is well-defined (it isn't quite straightforward, though).
- $\hat{\lambda}$ is unique, $\hat{\lambda}(\varnothing) = 0$ and $\hat{\lambda}_P \equiv \lambda$ (these were trivial).
- If $A,B \in R(P)$ are disjoint, then $\hat{\lambda}(A \cup B) = \hat{\lambda}(A) + \hat{\lambda}(B)$ (there's just one trick).
- **If $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are disjoint elements of $R(P)$, such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in R(P)$, then:**

$$\hat{\lambda} \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \hat {\lambda} (A_n) $$

**Thoughts:**

Using the fact that $\bigcup A_n \in R(P)$, let's write:

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^s I_k$$

For some disjoint $I_k$'s in $P$. Then:

$$\hat{\lambda} \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \hat{\lambda} \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^s I_k \right) = \sum_{k=1}^s \lambda(I_k)$$

I also thought that since $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^s I_k$, i.e. a finite union of elements of $P$, then at least one of these $I_k$'s should contain countably many $A_n$'s. But then what?!

I am not seeing the trick to be done here. Any input is appreciated.

Bonus question: do you know a good reference in which those elementary concepts are nicely treated?

Comment: Each $A_i$ is a union of elements of $P$, so you can rewrite each $A_i$ to be a disjoint union of $I_j$, which in turn allows you to use the second fact at the beginning.

Comment: @Clayton, so $\hat{\lambda}(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \hat{\lambda}( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\bigcup_{k=1}^{r_n} I_{n,k} ))$. I think I understand what to do now, but how can I do the work rigorously? How should I re-index or rename the $I_{n,k}$'s?